# Custom Bootstrap Pagination in Laravel error

Tags: laravel, pagination, bootstrap-4, custom-component

I follow the doc on the site
https://medium.com/appstract/custom-bootstrap-pagination-in-laravel-540922f71af0

but I got two question:
here is my code

```
Route::get(‘rows’, ‘ComeController@rows’);
```

first:

```
public function rows(Request $request)
{
$search_cons=$request->all();
$tablename=$search_cons[‘tablename’];
$search_alls = DB::table($tablename)
->where(‘product’,’=’,’5');

(1.)
    ->get();
    ?//it shows Method links does not exist
```

or

```
(2).
    ->>paginate(9);
    //it will ocupy the $perPage=9  when I use dd($search_alls)



   $page =   $request->get(‘page’, 1);
    $perPage = 6;
    $items = collect($myItems);
    return view(‘my.view’, [ ‘items’ => $items->forPage($page, $perPage), ‘pagination’ => BootstrapComponents::pagination($items, $page, $perPage, ‘’, [‘arrows’ => true]) ]);
}
```

Second:

```
when click the page link to the page2 just like http://…/rows?page=2
it shows Undefined index: tablename
```

Does I use the ->paginage(9)? but the $perpage is missing its function

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#279 ▼
  #total: 13
  #lastPage: 2
  #items: Collection {#262 ▶}
  #perPage: 9
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost:8000/comefoshowmain"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

And how can I fix the ?page=2 error?

---

Thanks for the reply

I just want to use pagination but my code show error when I click the page 2

here is my origin thought not using the bootstrap component

web.php

```
Route::get('rows','ProController@rows');
```

### ProController:

```
public function rows(Request $request)
{
    $search_cons=$request->all();

$tablename=$search_cons['tablename'];

$search_alls = DB::table($tablename)
    ->where('product','=','5')
    ->paginate(9);

    return View('pro.results')
            ->with('search_alls', $search_alls)
            ->with('table',$tablename);

};
```

### results.blade   view

```
<div class="container">
@foreach ($search_alls->chunk(3) as $chunks)
    <div class="row clearfix">
      @foreach($chunks as $searchall)
        <div class="col-md-4 column">
                <h3>
                    label
                </h3>
                <p>
                    something             
        </p>
        </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
{!! $search_alls->links() !!}
```

The first page work well

http://localhost:8000/rows?table=A16&...

when I click the second page

localhost:8000/rows?page=2

it shows

it shows Undefined index: tablename

Comment: What is the question? You have an error **Undefined index: tablename** OR **?page=2 error?** ? Can you specify your requirement changes other than usual pagination cases?
You don't need to worry about any other things if you follow the official **[Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination)** format.

Comment: @robspin Unclear your question Please describe more, then we will help you.

Comment: @EazySam I repost my question for the ?page=2

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I repost my question just use the laravel pagination function

Comment: use origin pagination I use this to fix .
{{ $users->appends($_GET)->links() }}
But can I use post methoud for pagination
route::post('rows','ProController@rows')
And {{ $users->appends($_POST)->links() }}  I got the erroe message   
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

Comment: I found the answer 
pagination only works with get parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes the reason because you need to append current querystring in pagination link this my code is

```
$input = Request::input();
$myModelsPaginator = App\Models\MyModel::paginate();
$myModelsPaginator->appends($input);
```

FOR YOU LIKE THIS

```
 $input = Request::input();
 $search_alls = DB::table($tablename)
 ->where(‘product’,’=’,’5');
->pagination(9);
 $searcg_alls->appends($input);
```

append you table name and all other input with page link so you not get table not found error

your question is not clear but assume as above you want is no then comment down may be i help you

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can I  use query builder to get the data from the DB. Not using Eloquent ORM because the table will change every query and the Model is,too.

Comment: But when I use the query builder, I must got the variable from the request. But can't send the request to the   ?page=2  as the page2 is the pagination function ,then the $tablename=$search_cons['tablename'] will make error report

Comment: becuase your table name is come from request right. and your pagination link not contain query string , first you append query string in pagination as above in ans i tell you how append query string into pagination link

Comment: thanks for your help. Can I  use post method on the pagination function?
As I go the error   message :  Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

Comment: I found the answer 
pagination only works with get parameters.

Comment: it possible using ajax on pagination , can you know ajax ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167507/discussion-between-ravindra-bhanderi-and-robspin).

Comment: I know the ajax how to achieve?

Comment: right and see the class of pagination anchertag  link and then  bind click event on and preventdefualt all event on click , final you get you want